# Swift nested completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I am making API calls and for that purpose I use completionHandlers in Swift. I came to issues where I need to call one function with completionHandler right after another one succeeds but the nested function is not called and main function does not return anything now.

Here is code:

```
func submit(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<MyResult, Error>) -> Void) {

    submitSerice.subit() { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let submitResponse):
            self?.getNextSession() { response in
                switch sessionResponse {
                case .success(let nextSession):
                    // do something and return submitResponse
                    completionHandler(.success(submitResponse))
                case .failure(let error):
                    completionHandler(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}


func getNextSession(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<NextSession, Error>) -> Void) {
    print("Calling getNextSession()")
    nextSesssionService.nextSession() { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            completionHandler(.success(response))
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

When getNextSession and submit are called alone everything works fine but here print "Calling getNextSession()" is not even shown in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how you've written this, a likely cause is that `self` is deallocated between the time you call `submit` and the time `submitSerice.subit` calls its completion handler. If you want to ensure that this operation completes, you should not use `[weak self]` here. You should hold a strong reference to ensure the operation completes. At a minimum, you should probably add logging if `self` is nil so that you know what's happened.

That said, I highly recommend [converting this to `async/await`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/updating_an_app_to_use_swift_concurrency). The code to handle serial execution of asynchronous operations will be dramatically simpler than when using completion handlers.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Yes that was the issues with my code. I will definitely look into async/await. I have started using completion handlers in my network calls but later i realised that it was not the best choice.